# How to combine lines within square braces?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having my lines in an array format. Like,

```
[[85.56100982   28.37353904    7.29312763    5.8686302     7.31323048
 2.67508181    3.12201964   19.1084619   144.15708275   43.80130902]
 [........................................................         ]]
```

Likewise I have like few thousand lines. I want to combine elements within each brace into a single line. I tried using "NWK" (to combine n number of lines) command but the problem is the lines within the square braces throughout the files are not equal. Is there a way where I can combine elements within braces to one single lines?

I am not able to explain with those huge decimal numbers, so I will just take the whole numbers and denote my output.

This is how my output should be like [[85 28 7 5 7 2 3 19 144 43]

```
                                  [.........................]]
```

Comment: can you give an example output?

Comment: Just edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I am not able to explain with those huge decimal numbers, so I will just take the whole numbers and denote my output.

[85  28 7  5 7 2 3 19 144  43]. This is how my output should be like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
f = open("thefile.txt")

f.read(1) # read the first opening bracket

nf = open("newfile.txt","w")
nf.write("[\n")

currentline = ""
for line in f:
    currentline += line[:-1]
    if line[-2] == "]":
        if line [-3] == "]": #last line"
            nf.write(currentline[:-1])
            break
        nf.write(currentline + "\n")
        currentline = ""
nf.write("\n]")
```